# Why does Chrome Developer Tools for mobile devices not work?

Tags: mobile, google-chrome-devtools, responsive

[image]
Since a few weeks my Chrome Developer Tools mobile device view doesn't work properly. When I change the view to mobile, tablet etc the display doesn't show the whole mobile display, but a portion of it and to see the full display, I have to scroll (vertical) (I've attached pictures).

It's definitely not the code but Chrome Developer Tools. Sometimes a page refresh helps, sometimes (mostly) nothing but time (it goes back to normal at random times). I searched for a while but can't really find anything related.

Comment: Do you have a link where I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I have no way to provide a link, the side is not deployed, just in my browser, when I use google chrome developer tools for mobile devices, Im getting those issues

Comment: It could be any number of issues. Without a reference where the issue reproduces this kind of thing is impossible to debug.